# How does Slark's Pounce work?

Tags: dota-2

I've been having trouble using Slark's Pounce. I've researched some of my problems but I couldn't find the information.

When I try to pounce I always land next to them, but not latch onto him/her. I've fooled around with Slark on the `-wtf` mode but I couldn't it figure out. Sometimes I would pounce past the target and I get killed.

I hope I have given enough info for you tell me how to use it properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pounce only works on heroes, you will pounce through creeps
2. To latch you need to hit the target while "in air" (700 range + 95 collision area).

It is a pretty straight forward ability... nothing weird about it so... not much else to tell. Check the link below for full details.

More details: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Slark

Answer (score 1):

Slark pounces in the direction `he is facing`. If you want to pounce to an enemy, just right click on him, so you can turn to him, then pounce. As you know, the hero always looks the way you have clicked

Comment: To add to this, there's also a turn rate to keep in mind. Simply right clicking to face and then immediately hitting the *Pounce* hotkey, you will often not get the full rotation. Give it just a moment longer if you have it to spare and you may see better results.

Answer (score 1):

First, imagine you're using Mirana's Leap skill; movement-wise, it works the same way. You instantly jump forward in the direction your hero is facing. It has nothing to do with where your mouse cursor may or may not be. Shadow Fiend's Shadowrazes are also similar in this way, except he fires an AoE nuke instead of actually jumping.

To latch someone, you have to **directly pass over** the target. If you make contact mid-air, you'll stop immediately, and the latch will connect and deal damage.

The "splash" effect when you land **is not an AoE.** This is one of the only skills that I thought that confusing visuals. Once you land, you're done; you have to have jumped over them like a hurdle in order for the latch to work.

Comment: Also you leap through BKB and latch can be escaped by blinks (but not Mirana's leap)

Comment: Yes, feel free to discuss the specific interactions with other items/skills here. I don't know all of them off the top of my head. I believe if you get stunned mid-air the leap finishes (and I think the latch even connects if you hit someone) but you can't do anything afterwards until the stun wears off.

Answer (score 1):

When you activate the ability "Pounce", Slark immediately flies forwards "through the air" (at 933.33 MS) in the direction Slark is facing.

If Slark makes contact with an enemy hero, Slark will stop flying, and stop where he hit the enemy hero. This tethers the enemy hero to a central point, and connect a line from the enemy hero the the central point. The enemy hero will not be allowed to move past farther than the line permits the enemy hero, unless use of a separate item such as "Force Staff", or "Blink Dagger".

This ability cannot hit creeps, enemy heroes, or illusions. This ability cannot be purged.

Source: [Dota 2 Wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Slark), 2000 hours of playing experience.

Answer (score 0):

Slark's pounce works in a really simple way.

The moment you click pounce, Slark will leap (like PotM) in the direction that he is facing currently.

Then, if there is **an enemy hero**, Slark will latch onto them and prevent them from escaping.

However, if there is no enemy hero, Slark will pounce through everything (units, terrain, even buildings, similar to leap.)